# Save multiple SQL jobs in single files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, jobs

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and I need to save every SQL agent job in single 'create in' *.sql files. The problem is that I got about 20 SQL Server with 15 (up to 51) SQL jobs.

How can I export these jobs easy in single files?

If I mark all jobs they will be saved in a single file. It would take to long to manually export every single job to a file.

Did someone have an idea?

Comment: Are you needing a single file for each server's jobs, or a single file for ALL of the jobs on all of your servers?  Also, what do you intend to do with this?

Comment: I need a single file for each server's jobs because the jobs were never in QA and it was decided to make an QA. Now I have to checkin the jobs in CVS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of our processes we are using Powershell to achieve this.. I am not sure of the link who has written, since it resides in our process, but below script might be useful to you.

```
param([String]$ServerListPath)
```

#Load the input file into an Object array

```
$ServerNameList = get-content -path $ServerListPath
```

#Load the SQL Server SMO Assemly

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null
```

#Create a new SqlConnection object

```
 $objSQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
```

#For each server in the array do the following

```
foreach($ServerName in $ServerNameList)

 {
 Try
 {
     $objSQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerName;Integrated   Security=SSPI;" 
         Write-Host "Trying to connect to SQL Server instance on $ServerName..." -NoNewline
        $objSQLConnection.Open() | Out-Null
        Write-Host "Success."
    $objSQLConnection.Close()
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White "Fail"
    $errText =  $Error[0].ToString()
        if ($errText.Contains("network-related"))
    {Write-Host "Connection Error. Check server name, port, firewall."}

    Write-Host $errText
    continue
}
```

#IF the output folder does not exist then create it

```
$OutputFolder = ".\$ServerName"
$DoesFolderExist = Test-Path $OutputFolder
$null = if (!$DoesFolderExist){MKDIR "$OutputFolder"}
```

#Create a new SMO instance for this

```
$ServerName
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $ServerName
```

#Script out each SQL Server Agent Job for the server

```
$srv.JobServer.Jobs | foreach {$_.Script() + "GO`r`n"} | out-file ".\$OutputFolder\jobs.sql"
```

#Use the command below to output each SQL Agent Job to a separate file. Remember to comment out the line above.

#Removed backslash character, typically seen in Replication Agent jobs, to avoid invalid filepath issue

#$srv.JobServer.Jobs | foreach-object -process

```
{out-file -filepath $(".\$OutputFolder\" + $($_.Name -replace '\\', '') + ".sql") -inputobject $_.Script() }
```

}

Comment: +1 looks like what I want. Unfortunately Powershell is deactived for the sql server but I will look to activate it.

Comment: @hellskitchen, hope it helps and kindly markup if answer is useful or correct if answered, you're welcome !

Answer (score 8):

There are two possible ways
1.  [Automatically create scripts for all SQL Server Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361163/automatically-create-scripts-for-all-sql-server-jobs)

2. I. Open Object Details

[image]

II. Select All Jobs (Shift + Mouse Click) -> Right Click -> Script Job as
     [image]

Comment: Love the feature in your 2nd answer - can never work out why it's "hidden" behind using Object Explorer Details +1

Comment: @MHSQLDBA Because the Object Explorer tree does not support multi-select.

Comment: I meant I can't work out the reason for not making it a feature on the Object Explorer tree - is there a good reason that it does not?

Comment: thanks, but in that way I only get a single file for all jobs not multiple files.

Answer (score 4):

I use Bill Graziano's [Script SQL Server Configuration](https://scriptsqlconfig.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex for this.
It can script the whole configuration of a SQL Server instance to .sql files, including SQL Server Agent jobs.

It is a command line utility, so with multiple servers to script, you can use a batch or PowerShell script to loop through all the servers.

Comment: project moved to github: http://github.com/billgraziano/ScriptSqlConfig